# Fourier transform and non-standard calculus

Tags: fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, distribution-theory, nonstandard-analysis

The Fourier transform is not as easily formalizable as the Fourier series. For example, one needs to introduce [tempered distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) to define the [Dirac delta-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). Also, it is impossible to view the Fourier transform as a projection of a vector from the Hilbert space of square-integrable functions on a certain orthonormal basis.

It seems, though, that the Dirac delta-function can be naturally [introduced](http://www.gauge-institute.org/delta/DeltaFunction.pdf) in [non-standard calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_calculus). It is a hyperreal function that is $1/dx$ in the interval $[-dx/2, dx/2]$ and zero everywhere else. Here, $dx$ is an infinitesimal hyperreal. But i could not find any treatments of the Fourier transform through non-standard calculus (though it seems to be fruitful and straightforward).

So, my question is: are there any works that treat the Fourier transform through non-standard calculus? Or, if not, are there any intrinsic technical difficulties? And, finally, if it can be done, is it possible to formalize the Fourier transform as a projection of a vector in a linear space of hyperreal functions onto an orthonormal basis?

Comment: As a side note, in order to define the Dirac delta, you don't need tempered distributions at all.